# Can't upload image only on mobile device Laravel + Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I read about this on some posts on the stack, but I still do not see the same case as mine. I can not upload the image on  phone device. I do not see why I do not have a console to see error. I'll show you the code, so someone who is experienced can see the error.

Laravel code to upload image:

```
public function uploadImage($car, $images)
{
    $fileName = Carbon::now()->timestamp . $images->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $images->move(public_path('public/images'), $fileName);
    if (!$path) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'An error has accured'], 500);
    }
    $carImage = new CarImages ([
        'path' => 'public/images/' . $fileName
    ]);

    $car->images()->save($carImage);
    return $carImage;
}
```

Laravel code for store form with image:

```
public function store(CarRequest $request)
{
    $file = null;
    if ($request->has('picture')) {
        $file = $request->file('picture');
    }
    $user = auth()->user();
    if ($user) {
        $car = Car::create([
            'car_type' => $request->input('car_type'),
            'mark' => $request->input('mark'),
            'model' => $request->input('model'),
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);
    }
    if (!$car) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Oooops, something went wrong'], 500);
    }
    if ($file) {
        $carImage = $this->uploadImage($car, $file);
    }
    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NotifyNewCarUpload($user, $car));
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Your car has been successfully added',
        'car' => $car,
        'user' => $user
    ], 201);
}
```

In CarRequest for upload for car i have:

```
  'car_type' => 'required',
  'mark' => 'required',
  'model' => 'required',
  'picture' => 'required|image'
```

In Vue.js insert car I have:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" 
 @submit.prevent="submit">
 ...
 ...
        <div class="col-3 insert-vehicle-right">
           <div :class="{ 'error': errors.has('file') }" v-if="!imgSrc" class="image-upload-holder"></div>
            <img :class="{ 'error': errors.has('file') }" v-if="imgSrc" class="uploaded-image" :src="imgSrc" alt="uploaded image"/>
              <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <button class="btn action-btn">Upload Photo</button>
                <input name="file"
                       v-validate="'required'"
                       type="file"
                       @change="onFileChange"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn action-btn save-btn">Save</button>
            </div>
 </form>
```

Vue.js  javascript code for upload and preview image code:

```
  onFileChange(event) {
    this.picture = event.target.files[0];
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.imgSrc = URL.createObjectURL(this.picture);
  },
```

And i have formData code for post that code:

```
 ...
 ...
formdata.append('picture', this.picture);
```

It's not working on mobile phones. Does anyone recognize the reason?
All my pictures are stored in the laravela folder public/public/images and work good on web browser (destop and laptop device). Also i have table for storing path images.. Only for phone device not work. Help?

Comment: did you checked in browser's mobile view. There you could check error in console

Comment: For now not. I am waiting for an experienced programmer to confirm that he sees a mistake somewhere in my code. I wrote it in detail :)

Comment: then you have wait for life long :-), check with different mobile devices as well. . .

Comment: I catch error 
"The picture failed to upload."
Why?

Comment: @RasaMohamed Did you know why picture failded to upload?

Comment: Can you add `accept="image/*"` to your input type, also check with different browser and mobile. Let me know

Comment: I set accept="image/*" but again same error.
I don't know did error in backend or frontend?

Comment: Make a log file and track that every data is passing while uploading images from mobile. then check that log file is there anything missing

Comment: I find probably error. Image which have more than 2mb make error in phone. How to resize image mb in laravel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191019/discussion-between-rasa-mohamed-and-alex-al).

Answer (score 0):

Okey problem was be in php.ini configuraction and max_size_upload file. I only set more than 2mb images file and work perfecty.
@thanks Rasa